# Laravel socialite callback method doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite, php-7.0

I'm trying to add Facebook authetication via SocialiteProviders, but it looks like method `redirectToProvider` does work, but `handleProviderCallback` doesn't. So it redirects me to the facebook/vk page, but there are no callback.

Can you explain me, when callback method is called?

I tried to create empty file in callback method just to check it's work, but nothing happens.

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider) {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

public function handleProviderCallback($provider) {
        $user = Socialite::with($provider)->user();
        $file = fopen("info.txt", "w");
        fwrite($file, $user->name);
        fwrite($file, $user->email);
        fclose($file);
    }
```

Comment: So in your routes file you should have a route that binds to handleProviderCallback. You also need to check that it is listed in your services conf file. And that the route matches with what you supplied facebook app

Comment: @Anders it is in my routes file. `Route::get('/auth/{provider}/callback', 'AuthenticationController@handleProviderCallback')` What should be listed in services conf file?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to put url to my {provider}/callback in services.php and it worked. Thank you, @Anders